# Unable to access Azure SQL Server from Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops, virtual-machine

Following the Azure VM cluster tutorial provided by Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/create-vm-cluster-with-infrastructure),

I have a resource group created in Azure.
Under the Resource group, I have created VN, subnets, etc.

Now, I have two VMs created in the resources group. Both of them have a LoadBalancer on top. I have added NAT rule to LB to connect to individual instance, while they both share the same frontend IP.
[image]

I have created a new resource Azure MSSQL server, in the Firewall rule of the SQL server, added the public ip of the LB to the Azure Server
[image]

I have now logged in to the individual VMs, and tried to access the SQL server from the VM, but I am unable to connect to it.

I tried normal `ping <hostname>`
it fails `133 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 295ms`

Then I try telnet from IP address (ip address was received from ping )
and I get

```
Trying <ip_address>...
Connected to <ip_address>.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

When I try to connect using an application, I get this error

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset ClientConnectionId:8b2f0e3b
-fda0-41af-b8dc-ce80d0760b82
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.jav
a:3806) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:2109) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2
.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.prelogin(SQLServerConnection.java
:3517) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection
.java:3325) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:29
50) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnecti
on.java:2790) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:
1663) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1064) ~[
mssql-jdbc-11.2.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at jet.server.db.core.ConnectorManager$ConnectionPool.£(ConnectorManager.java:712) ~[
JRESServlets.jar:?]
        at jet.server.db.core.ConnectorManager$ConnectionPool.connect(ConnectorManager.java:4
32) ~[JRESServlets.jar:?]
        at jet.server.db.core.ConnectorManager$ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectorManager.
java:504) ~[JRESServlets.jar:?]
        at jet.server.db.core.ConnectorManager$ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectorManager.
java:487) ~[JRESServlets.jar:?]
        at jet.server.db.core.DatabaseImpl.open(DatabaseImpl.java:839) ~[JRESServlets.jar:?]
        at jet.server.db.core.GlobalDataService.<init>(GlobalDataService.java:103) ~[JRESServ
lets.jar:?]
        at jet.server.db.core.GlobalDataService.init(GlobalDataService.java:37) ~[JRESServlet
s.jar:?]
        at jet.server.ServerEnv.K(ServerEnv.java:2322) ~[JRESServlets.jar:?]
```

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL is only available through TCP port **`1433`**. Check whether firewall is allowed outgoing TCP communication on port **`1433`**.

[image]

You can check the connection by using below command:

```
Test-NetConnection -Port 1433 -ComputerName ServerName.database.windows.net
```

**To resolve the error**, make sure to open firewall in the path from Server like Windows Firewall, Corporate Firewall or Azure NSG (Network security group to allow access.

*In the Azure SQL Server, select Networking and **enable** the below option:*

[image]

Connect to the Azure Virtual Machine and restart SQL Server like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[IP firewall rules - Azure SQL Database  | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure?view=azuresql#connections-from-inside-azure)

Comment: Thanks.
I had to enable the firewall private and that worked.